# Two questions on Noetherian domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension $1$, $\mathfrak a$ is a non-zero ideal in $A$, then $\mathfrak a$ has a minimal primary decomposition $\mathfrak a=\bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathfrak q_i$, where each $\mathfrak q_i$ is $\mathfrak p_i$-primary. Since $\dim A=1$, each non-zero prime ideal of $A$ is maximal. But

> Why $\mathfrak p_i$ are distinct maximal ideals?
>
> Why every primary ideal is a prime power?

Comment: Q1 follows from Q2 since $p^n \cap p^m=p^{\max(n,m)}$. Hence Q2 is the interesting one!

Comment: @user: The question I'm interested in is: Given a 1-dimensional noetherian domain, is it true that each primary ideal is a power of a prime ideal ?

Answer (score 2):

Minimal primary decomposition implies that $\mathfrak p_i$ are pairwise distinct and since they contain $\mathfrak a$ must be non-zero which in a ring of dimension one is equivalent to maximal.

If every primary ideal is a prime power then $A$ is Dedekind, so in general is not true what you said.

**Edit.** If $A$ is a Noetherian domain of dimension $1$ and every primary ideal is a prime power then $A$ is Dedekind.

*Proof.* Every ideal has a primary decomposition which means that, in fact, every ideal can be written as an intersection of prime powers. But different prime powers of different prime ideals are pairwise comaximal (since $\dim A=1$), so every ideal is a product of prime powers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a reference for the statement in the last sentence ?

Comment: @tj_ I have added few words to my answer in order to make it clear.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks. (the bounty will be awarded in 17 hours)